# Number of involutory matrices of order n.

Tags: linear-algebra

I am trying to find number of involutory matrices $(A^{2}=I)$  of order $n$ with entries as only $0$ and $1$ over the field of reals. But i did not get any formula of it. For order $2$ there are only two such matrices. Is there any way to find general formula to find number of such matrices? Please suggest me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every permutation of $n$ objects which consists of disjoint transpositions corresponds to such a matrix.

If there are two $1$s in any row, then doing the multiplication shows there must be zeros in the rows corresponding to those entries except in the corresponding column where you want the multiplication to come out as $1$. In that column one of the rows will have $1$, but the other will have $0$. That makes a complete row of zeros, zero determinant and no answer.

So any such matrix must be the matrix of a permutation of order $2$, and must therefore represent a product of disjoint 2-cycles.

So now you need to count those.

Note: a permutation matrix is a matrix with all zeros except for a $1$ in each row and in each column. When you multiply by such a matrix you get a permutation of the basis vectors - hence the name.

Comment: its means answer is number of product of 2-cycles in Sn?

Comment: @YOGESH The 2-cycles need to be disjoint (everything is a product of 2-cycles) - and don't forget the identity.

Comment: then how answer is 2 if n=2

Comment: @YOGESH If $n=2$ you have the identity and the permutation $(1,2)$ for $n=3$ you have identity plus $(1,2); (1,3); (2,3)$ - look it up on the online encyclopedia of integer sequences under $1, 2, 4, 10, 26$. See https://oeis.org/A000085

Comment: can i say number of elements of order 1 and 2 in Sn?

Comment: @YOGESH That should work

Comment: @YOGESH I've added a comment at the end of the answer.

Comment: ok thanks a lot

Comment: There are only 16 matrices of order 5 but according to yours  formula its different..

Comment: @YOGESH There are three kinds. The identity. Ten with three ones on the leading diagonal. Fifteen with a single one on the leading diagonal (three for each of the five fixed points).